# Como incluir um valor em uma matriz separando um dígito em cada coluna?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desenvolvi um programa que, ao informar um valor, este valor é alocado em todas as colunas da linha, me retornando uma matriz como essa:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
    [233, 233, 233],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]])]
```

Porém, gostaria que fosse separado por dígitos, assim:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 3],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]])]
```

Ou seja, ao informar um valor `233` gostaria que ele fosse separado por unidade e, cada unidade populando uma coluna. Poderiam me auxiliar? Tentei fazer algumas alterações no código, porém não alcancei meu objetivo.

Meu código:

```
LINHAS = 6
COLUNAS = 3
ab = numpy.zeros((LINHAS, COLUNAS), dtype=int)

while True:
  index += 1
  ac = int(input('Insira um numero de 3 digitos:')
  ab[index] = ac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito o que você quer é digitar um número de três dígitos e o programa joga cada dígito em uma coluna, isso pra cada linha da matriz. Certo? Então seu programa poderia ser assim:

```
import numpy

LINHAS = 6
COLUNAS = 3
ab = numpy.zeros((LINHAS, COLUNAS), dtype=int)
for i in range(LINHAS):
    ac = input('Insira um numero de 3 digitos:')
    ab[i] = list(ac)

print(ab)
```

Comment: vlw, eu tava querendo fazer isso  mesmo

Comment: só uma sugestão, seja mais específico no que você quer que o programa faça quando fizer uma pergunta, pq tem mais chance de você conseguir a resposta que você procura. Valeu!

Comment: Saquei, pode deixar :D